# How to import typescript function in a expo app in a yarn monorepo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo created with yarn workspaces, in it I have a project of components and utility functions written with typescript and I want to use them in the bare expo app

But when I try to import some function from the project it tries to import from node_modules and complains about the typescript syntax, how can I make it import directly from the project?

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/ui-base/src/utils/sizeHelper.ts 3:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:17)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
| 
> const vh = (value: number) => (Dimensions.get("window").height / 100) * value;
| 
| const vw = (value: number) => (Dimensions.get("window").width / 100) * value;

web compiled with 6 errors
```

root package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "omnijs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.5.0"
}
```

root tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
        "paths": {
            "ui-base/*": ["./packages/ui-base/*"]
        }
    },
    "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

typescript project tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "name": "ui-base",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./src/index.ts",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.1",
        "babel-preset-expo": "~9.5.0",
        "prettier": "3.0.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.72.3",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
        "styled-components": "5.3.11",
        "tsup": "^7.2.0"
    }
}
```

expo project tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig"
}
```

expo project package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@omnijs/flix",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.32.6",
    "@tanstack/router": "^0.0.1-beta.53",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~49.0.5",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "ui-base": "*",
    "zustand": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.1.2",
    "@types/expo": "^33.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.2",
    "prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

expo project metro.config.js:

```js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
/**
 * @type {import('expo/metro-config')}
 */
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

// Find the project and workspace directories
const projectRoot = __dirname;
// This can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
const workspaceRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [workspaceRoot];
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(workspaceRoot, 'node_modules'),
];
// 3. Force Metro to resolve (sub)dependencies only from the `nodeModulesPaths`
config.resolver.disableHierarchicalLookup = true;

module.exports = config;
```